# How cycle through applications in Xubuntu without using Alt-Tab?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, xfce

I don't like the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> function and just want to loop through my bottom application at the bottom bar with shortcuts. 
Here is a screenshot with applications at the bottom of screen:

[image: 1]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to use just one key for all of them, or have a different key for each application?

Answer (score 8):

That seems to be what "Switch application" does in Xfce.

Go to **Settings > Window Manager** and select **Keyboard** tab. In the left column "Action", look for "Switch application". Select the row, then either press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key or double-click on mouse. A small window will appear, ready to accept key press and register a new shortcut.

[image: Xfce Window Manager - Switch application]

The action has no shortcut, therefore does nothing, by default. When enabled, the action will switch applications immediately from one to another.

The behaviour of "Switch application":

- Unlike "Cycle windows" or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, the popup window will *not* be displayed.
- The action does *not* switch to all currently running programs.
- For example, the action can *not* switch to Settings Manager but can switch to Application Finder in Xfce 4.10 (14.04) and newer. The result is reversed in older system i.e. Xfce 4.8 (12.04).
- From my observation, the action will switch from oldest running program to newest running program and repeat the loop. The switching order is likely non-customizable.

Not all programs are applications. Some program has different type of window (dialog) compared to other programs (normal). The window type can be checked by using `xwininfo -wm` command.

Enable "Switch application" and try it for yourself.

Comment: For me, Switch Application goes through every window, including multiple windows for xfce4-terminal and Chrome.